# Why is Spring Security returning a "403 forbidden" when I try to make a request to an endpoint that I'm supposed to be allowed access?

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm building a web application with Spring and React. When I try to make a request to "/products/all", the server returns a "403 forbidden" after login, when the user is already authenticated.

Here is my implementation of UserDetails.
**Person**

```
package HardwareStore.hardware.data;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED, force = true)
@Entity
public class Person implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private final String firstname;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private final String lastname;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private final String username;
    private final String password;
    private final String email;
    private String type;
    private Double discount;
    private Double credit;
    private final String phoneNumber;
    private final String cedula;
    private final String province;
    private final String street;
    private final Integer localeNumber;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idPerson")
    private List<Invoice> invoices;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idPerson")
    private List<Payment> payments;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now, the implementation of UserDetailsService:
**PersonDetailsService**

```
import HardwareStore.hardware.data.Person;
import HardwareStore.hardware.data.PersonRepository;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class PersonDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepo;

    @Autowired
    public PersonDetailsService(PersonRepository personRepo) {
        this.personRepo = personRepo;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Person person = personRepo.findByUsername(username);

        if (person != null) {
            System.out.println("User authorities: " + person.getAuthorities());
            return person;
        }

        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
                "User '" + username + "' not found");
    }
}
```

I decided to print the authorities to verify that it has the expected role("ROLE_USER"). The console prints: User authorities: [ROLE_USER]. Just as expected.

I have a controller(AuthController) that processes login and registration:
**AuthController**

```
import HardwareStore.hardware.data.Person;
import HardwareStore.hardware.data.PersonRepository;
import HardwareStore.hardware.security.LoginRequest;
import HardwareStore.hardware.security.RegistrationRequest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController {

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository personRepo;

    public AuthController(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
            PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, PersonRepository personRepo) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.personRepo = personRepo;
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager
                .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(),
                        loginRequest.getPassword()));

        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="comment">
        /*
         * <SecurityContextHolder> holds SecurityContext, which is an object
         * used to store an Authentication object that holds the details of the
         * currently authenticated user.
         *
         * Therefore when an user logs in, the SecurityContext has to be updated
         * with the recently created "authentication" object.
         */
//</editor-fold>
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        Person person = (Person) authentication.getPrincipal();
        if (person.getType() != null) {
            /*
             * When the user logs in, this message is sent to the React application
             * to verify that the user has the expected role(ROLE_USER).
             */
            String message = authentication.isAuthenticated()
                    ? "User" + person.getUsername() + " of type " + person.getType()
                    + "; with authorities: " + person.getAuthorities() + " is succesfully authenticated!"
                    : "User authentication failed";
            return ResponseEntity.ok(message);
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(person.getFirstname() + " " + person.getLastname());
    }

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@RequestBody RegistrationRequest registrationRequest) {
        if (personRepo.findByUsername(registrationRequest.getUsername()) != null) {
            return ResponseEntity
                    .badRequest()
                    .body("Error: Username is already taken!");
        }

        if (personRepo.findByEmail(registrationRequest.getEmail()) != null) {
            return ResponseEntity
                    .badRequest()
                    .body("Error: Email is already in use!");
        }

        Person person = registrationRequest.toPerson(passwordEncoder);
        if (person.getType() == null) {
            person.setType("C");
        }
        personRepo.save(person);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("User registered successfully!");
    }
}
```

After login, the console in the React application shows: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0Eyq.png)

In the **Security Config** class, I've indicated that only users with the role "USER" can access the endpoint: "/products/all", but even though the user is already authenticated and has that role, the server responds with 403.

Here's my Security Config. It has a lot of useless code from my previous attempts to solve the problem(by googling and reading answers in Stackoverlfow). I left it there so you guys can know what I've tried and maybe explain why it didn't worked.

As far as I'm concerned, the configuration in the "configure(HttpSecurity http)" method should be enough to allow me to do exactly what I want, but that isn't the case. The only way to access "/products/all" is by uncommenting the commented line and including it in the "permitAll()" config.

**SecurityConfig**

```
import HardwareStore.hardware.data.PersonRepository;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.LazyCsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        prePostEnabled = true,
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private PersonDetailsService personDetailsService;

    private PersonRepository personRepo;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(personDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(encodePassword());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                //                .antMatchers("/auth/**", "/products/all").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/products/all").hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
    }

    @Bean
    public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter customAuthFilter() throws Exception {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter = new CustomAuthenticationFilter(objectMapper());
        authenticationFilter.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login", "POST"));
        authenticationFilter.setUsernameParameter("username");
        authenticationFilter.setPasswordParameter("password");
        authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler());
        authenticationFilter.setSessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy());

        return authenticationFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler() {
        return new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler("/");
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy(Arrays.asList(
                new ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy(),
                new CsrfAuthenticationStrategy(csrfTokenRepository())
        ));
    }

    @Bean
    public CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        return new LazyCsrfTokenRepository(new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository());
    }

    @Bean
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="comment">
    /*
     * CORS: Cross-origin resource sharing, is an specification that allows the
     * developer to specify what kind of cross domain request are authorized. It
     * is a protection mechanism implemented by browsers.
     *
     * <CorsFilter>: Filter that handles CORS preflight requests and intercepts
     * CORS simple and actual requests thanks to a CorsProcessor implementation
     * (DefaultCorsProcessor by default) in order to add the relevant CORS
     * response headers (like Access-Control-Allow-Origin) using the provided
     * CorsConfigurationSource (for example an UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource
     * instance.
     *
     * This bean is used to configure CORS request. It uses a CorsConfiguration
     * object to do this coniguration, that is contained within a
     * UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource object
     */
//</editor-fold>
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        // Don't do this in production, use a proper list  of allowed origins
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept"));
        config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
        //Register a CorsConfiguration for the specified path pattern.
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new PersonDetailsService(personRepo);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encodePassword() {
        return new StandardPasswordEncoder("encoder");
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper();
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you tried to replace .antMatchers("/products/all").hasRole("USER") with .antMatchers("/products/all").hasRole("ROLE_USER") ?

Comment: Does the 2nd request (the one after auth) include the JSESSIONID cookie?

Comment: @LunguDaniel Yes. It didn't worked. Besides, internally, the "hasRole()" method places "ROLE_" before its argument.

Comment: @Michael I'm new to Spring, so if you could explain what a JSESSIONID cookie is and why I need it, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: When you send auth request, the server replies with a set cookie header on the response for a token called JSESSIONID. Your browser should add this cookie to subsequent requests, as part of the request header. This token is how Spring knows what the session is, and that the user has previously been authenticated. So if it is omitted, Spring will 403 those following requests. It can be omitted by certain JavaScript GET requests if you are not careful about what params you use; that's what usually happens for me. You can use Chrome devtools to inspect the headers for requests and responses.

Comment: How do you handle the authentication ? Via a session ? a cookie ?

Comment: @Michael Thanks man! That solved the issue.